# How to implement kind of sumator in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to implement predicate which will works in mode with all variables not substituted
sum(X,Y,Z) will generate all numbers which fill that conditional X+Y=Z.
Well actually i can generate list of next numbers in that way.

```
lisst([_]).
lisst([_|Y]) :- lisst(Y).
fill([]).
fill([0|Xs]) :- fill(Xs).
fill([1|Xs]) :- fill(Xs).
fill([2|Xs]) :- fill(Xs).
fill([3|Xs]) :- fill(Xs).
fill([4|Xs]) :- fill(Xs).
fill([5|Xs]) :- fill(Xs).
fill([6|Xs]) :- fill(Xs).
fill([7|Xs]) :- fill(Xs).
fill([8|Xs]) :- fill(Xs).
fill([9|Xs]) :- fill(Xs).



concat_number(D,N) :- concat_number(D,N,0).
concat_number([],M,M).
concat_number([H|T],N,M) :- M1 is M*10+H, concat_number(T,N,M1).

    sum2(X,Y,Z) :-lisst(X),fill(X),lisst(Y),fill(Y),concat_number(X,X1), concat_number(Y,Y1), Z is X1 + Y1.
```

and my ask to prolog is ?- sum2(X,Y,Z). but it does not work well only Y number is changing.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error (on SWI-Prolog). Btw., the idiomatic way of enumerating finite lists is `length(L,_)`.

Comment: Undefined procedure: `concat_number`. Also, `X` is a singleton variable in that definition.

Comment: Please edit your original question; comments are no good for long pieces of code. Also, please rethink your question and try to come with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you encounter is due to Prolog's depth-first search control algorithm: because `Y` has an infinite number of values, Prolog never backtracks beyond the choice point for it. You should implement an [iterative deepening search](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Prolog/Search_techniques) algorithm, like

```
length(XY, _),       % backtrack over lists in order of length
X=[_|_],             % constrain X and Y to be non-empty
Y=[_|_],
append(X, Y, XY),    % break XY into X and Y
fill(XY),            % fill X and Y in one go
concat_number(X,I),
concat_number(Y,J),
Z is I+J.
```

Comment: any version without append append generate garbage

Comment: hmm and how to do not generate many same answers like [0,4], [0,0.4] ok i remove fill(0|Xs) on the end of fill

Comment: @user1262568: doing this by generating lists and converting those to numbers is what causes many of the duplicates. You'd be better off generating integers directly with a predicate such as `int(0). int(N) :- int(M), N is M+1.`

Comment: but then again there is a problem with not changing X variavble it will be all time 0

Comment: @user1262568: not if you adapt the algorithm I posted. I.e., you should only generate one integer `Z`, then break that into `X` and `Y` parts.

Comment: hmm but is will not works with unsubstituded variables but i will try

Comment: i tryed to make it like int(Z) sum(W,R,X), sum(W1,R1,Y) Z is X + Y but it does not work also

Comment: @user1262568, hint: use the `between` predicate, then subtract, don't add.

Comment: is it possible without using such bulit in predicates ?

Comment: Yes, if you redefine them. `between` is very simple.

Comment: but what range use in between or make it so between(-inf,Z,X)

Comment: but alsow i think it will be great if it coudl find sub(-2,4,2) in not many steps mhm...

Comment: perhaps i made to many conditionals but it can works only on nonnegative integers but when put cuts to avoid  inf loop in such question ?-sum(X,Y,2). –